# EasyMock record phase mock as argument

Tags: java, testing, easymock

Is it possibile with `EasyMock` during the register phase to register a method call whose arguments is a mock? E.g:

```
String s = 'a string';

ClassA a = createMock(ClassA.class);
ClassB b = createMock(ClassB.class);
ClassC c = createMock(ClassC.class);

expect(c.bFactoryMethod()).andReturn(b);
a.someMethod(s, b);
replayAll();

ClassToTest toTest = new ClassToTest();
toTest.wrapperMethodThatCallsSomeMethod(s);
verifyAll();
```

`EasyMock` complains about:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having a mock in parameter to a mocked method is perfectly valid. In your case, I suspect that `a.someMethod(s, b)` is not a void method. So you should indeed record a return value.

I also don't see how `a` and `b` are injected into `ClassToTest`. But I guess this code was left out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a call to `EasyMock.expectLastCall()` right after the call to `a.someMethod(s, b)`, to have it registered with EasyMock.

Comment: No. Assuming that `a.someMethod(s, b)` is returning void, expectLastCall is optional. However, if it is returning something, you need to have `expect(a.someMethod(s, b).andReturn(xxx)`